# Creating a Dropdown Menu from Database

Tags: cakephp, drop-down-menu

I'm trying to create a Dropdown menu from the table Holidays for the column name. But I'm too dumb to make it work.

I already tried some of the things people wrote but most of them have a second database. But I only have one.

My goal is to show all the names from the Holiday name column so, if I create a new holiday, I just get the name of the date from the Dropdown menu and don't need to write it down every time.

HolidaysController.php

```php
public function index()
    {
        $holidays = $this->paginate($this->Holidays);
        $this->set(compact('holidays'));
        $name =$this->name->find('list');
        $this->set(compact('name')); 
    }
```

Holidays add.ctp

```php
        <?php
            echo $this->Form->control('date', array('label' => __('Datum', true)));
            echo $this->Form->control('name', ['options' => $name, 'empty' => true]);
        ?>
```

I thought he would show me now a dropdown list from the names of the holidays but i just have a normal field and get the error:

> Notice (8): Undefined variable: name [APP/Template\Holidays\add.ctp, line 19]

I'm probably missing something really basic here, I'm still learning coding so if I missed any information, you need, just let me know.

EDIT:

My add function after the edit

HolidaysController

```php
public function add()
    {
        $name =$this->name->find('list');
        $this->set(compact('name')); 
        $holiday = $this->Holidays->newEntity();
        if ($this->request->is('post')) {
            $holiday = $this->Holidays->patchEntity($holiday, $this->request->getData());
            if ($this->Holidays->save($holiday)) {
                $this->Flash->success(__('Der Feiertag wurde gespeichert.'));

                return $this->redirect(['action' => 'index']);
            }
            $this->Flash->error(__('Der Feiertag wurde nicht gespeichert. Bitte, versuchen sie es erneut.'));
        }
        $this->set(compact('holiday'));
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must find and set list in your add() method, like :

```
public function add()
{
    // your add code here .. then:
    $name =$this->Holidays->find('list');
    $this->set(compact('name')); 
}
```

By default every controller method has own view template:

```
index() >> index.ctp
add() >> add.ctp
edit() >> edit.ctp
myCustomMethod() >> my_custom_method.ctp
// ...
```

EDIT:

> If I add your code to function add() i get an Error: Call to a member
>   function find() on string.

I copy code from your question. But you must update:

from: `$this->name->find('list');` to

```
$this->Holidays->find('list', [
    'keyField' => 'name',
]);
```

Comment: If I add your code to function add() i get an Error: Call to a member function find() on string.

Comment: I copy code from your question, and give you idea how to. My Answer is updated.

Comment: I finally understand now how it works. I can now choose the names from the Database. Now i just need to find out why it saves as a number and not as the holidays name. Ty for your help.

Comment: It saves as a number because your list has numeric IDs as keys. I've update the answer above with an easy solution.